# Mountain Lion Challenge - ask, answer, blog and win Apple products!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion

**Congratulations to our winners!**

For asking a Nice Question:

- [Felix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/25735/felix)
- [Nathan Greenstein](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/2220/nathan-greenstein)
- [Viktor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/8551/viktor)

For asking a Popular Question:

- [Vivart](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/7451/vivart)
- [KMC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/6916/kmc)
- [Dennis Madsen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/17423/dennis-madsen)

For giving a Nice Answer:

- [Scot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/15562/scot)
- [meeee](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/25826/meeee)
- [XAleXOwnZX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/8320/xalexownzx)

For being a Bounty Hunter:

- [Mathias Bynens](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/4408/mathias-bynens)
- [eggyal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/8331/eggyal)
- [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike)

For being a Blogger:

- [Daniel Lawson](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9388/daniel-lawson)
- [Patrix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/patrix)
- [Stuffe](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9495/stuffe)

And the winner of our Grand Prize Challenge is... [houbysoft](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1035/houbysoft)!

Thanks to everyone who participated, and I hope you enjoyed the contest. Winners will be contacted via email to arrange prize shipping.

---

[Mountain Lion](http://www.apple.com/osx/) is the next major iteration of Apple's OS, and it was officially released today. To celebrate, we are holding a contest with lots of chances to win Apple products, including a grand prize package worth upwards of $500!

[image: Apple Prizes]

To win, do as you always do! Ask and answer awesome questions about [mountain-lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountain-lion). There will also be an opportunity to win prizes by writing posts for the [Ask Different Blog](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/).

For rules and more details, see the [Mountain Lion Challenge](http://mountainlionchallenge.com/) page.

Comment: The [List all new OS X Mountain Lion features](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57349/please-share-new-features-which-you-have-discovered-in-os-x-mountain-lion) question seems like it'll game this contest hard, if [the previous iterations](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) are to judge. Could CW questions be excepted from this?

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that CW should be excluded. It seems unfair to reward one person for something that's designed to be a community collaboration.

Comment: I agree also. The poster of the CW question being discussed made similar comments in chat this morning; I don't suspect this policy would draw any complaints if we excluded CW.

Comment: I also think that CW posts should be excluded. They distort the challenge.

Comment: What is CW? Thanks.

Comment: CW stands for Community Wiki.  The reason they would like it excluded is because the questions are usually vague, like: What are some great hidden features in Mountain Lion.  They usually get a huge amount of up votes and the answers in them get them too, see example: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/82/24141 People would like them excluded because they aren't like the regular questions that people ask on here. And someone could win this contest easily with this kind of CW question.

Comment: Good points. I'll think about how best to deal with this in the future. I don't want to go back and make people ineligible who have already completed the ML challenges, so I'm going to leave it in for this contest. Keep in mind that we are doing a raffle though - so while people may earn entries from a CW question, the huge amount of upvotes won't give them an unfair advantage (i.e., there's no advantage to going higher once you get 10 upvotes, or 1000 views, etc)

Comment: @Lauren Do keep in mind that three of the four people who requested this policy are three of the four people who qualified for the drawing on the basis of that post.

Comment: w00t :) congrats guys! :)

Comment: So when i will get my gift?

Comment: @Vivart if you haven't gotten it yet, please send me an email with your order information and full name.

Comment: This question is closed since the relevant promotion is over and that code inactive.

Answer (score 7):

I favor to **exclude CW posts from the mountainlionchallenge<sup>TM</sup>** as it distorts the results.

On Ask Different posts are made community wikis mostly because:

- multiple people worked on an answer but only one get's the votes
- collect gems which Apple hides in their software

Excluding CW posts will encourage communal editing to provide the best answers and hints without giving some people an unfair head start in the challenge.

Comment: And, in point of fact, all the posts that have already qualified for the contest as of 24 hours after the announcement are related to one particular Community-Wiki question. A good case for excluding CW posts from the contest.

Comment: I would support this as well since CW as it exists now is to allow people to ask "the obvious" and not have it skew reputation or points.

Answer (score 5):

**Thank you** for making this entirely raffle-based. That, combined with the higher (10-score) bar for quality should produce better results than the last contest.

Answer (score 3):

I'm writing a Blog Post (one that I always intended to write), and it's going to be more than 750 Characters - is this OK?  It's not massively over, it will be approaching a thousand words.

Comment: It should be fine. The upper limit is meant to dictate the kind of scope we're interested in rather than be a hard cutoff. Feel free to run your draft by us in the [blog chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1408/ask-different-blog).

Comment: Oh, and when I say 750 characters, I mean WORDS!

Comment: Twitter has warped our thinking.