# Suppress or reposition the Mountain Lion Challenge wherever a question is explicitly about a different version of OS X or Mac OS X

Tags: discussion

It's nice to have awareness of the challenge.

However, it's potentially **confusing – especially for newcomers** – to have Mountain Lion so prominent *below the title* of every question that is specifically **not** about Mountain Lion.

Placement in the **midst** of each question is not ideal.

An example:

[image]

Answers below assume that it will be possible (and relatively easy) to treat the challenge, or its banner, differently wherever a question:

- **is** [leopard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leopard), [snow-leopard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snow-leopard) or [lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lion)
- **and is not** [mountain-lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountain-lion)

– and so on.

---

This is admittedly a late suggestion, if there are only nine days left for this particular banner/challenge/competition, but it could be food for thought before the next banner is placed.

Answer (score 1):

Have there been any comments or links or conversation of this being confusing to actual newcomers? (Or are you placing yourself in their shoes?)

I think this banner is a very good way to ensure everyone who visits knows that we are actively seeking participation from newcomers - especially if they have arrived here for reasons other than Mountain Lion launch.

Comment: Confusing for me sometimes, and I'm familiar with the site, which is why I began thinking about newcomers. Certainly the banner is a good way of raising awareness but its placement in the **midst** of a question can be troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

## Suppress the banner

Keep it simple. Suppress the wide banner, unrelated to the question, that appears between the title of the question and the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

## Make better use of the sidebar

The community bulletin, already in the sidebar, already links to a Mountain Lion '[contest](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/mountain-lion-challenge-ask-answer-blog-and-win-apple-products)' that ends in a few days.

Adapt the bulletin to link primarily to the Mountain Lion '[challenge](http://mountainlionchallenge.com)'.